# Putting Dates for Short Experience Period

Tags: resume, job-search, new-job, job-change, work-experience

Some of my work experience are more than 1 year so I can easily put dates for them on my resume in this format: Year1 - Year3

But I also got some work experience which last a few months only. So, in this case, can I still put them in such format (like Year4 - Year4)?

What would you suggest?

Comment: I always put in my start and stop dates down to the exact day. It impresses the natives when several years are involved :) And it also helps when I have memory issues with some events in my life and I need to correlate them with a baseline tmeline :)

Answer (score 3):

> But I also got some work experience which last a few months only. So,
>   in this case, can I still put them in such format (like Year4 -
>   Year4)?

You could.

When the duration is less than one year, you might consider including the month in addition to the year. For example:

Acme Widget Company (March 2002 - December 2002)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Joe. Can I still keep others with just years, while these ones are with months and years? Is it ok?

Comment: Yes. Your focus should be imparting clear information in your resume, even if it means sacrificing your consistency with the `Year A - Year B` format.